# How to send group emails asp.net/C# depending on select query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send a group email depending on emails gathered from a select query called `emailresults`.

This is the code I have got so far but I am receiving error:

> Could not send the e-mail - error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("queensqsis@gmail.com", "queensqsis@gmail.com");// to & from

message.To.Add(emailresult);
message.Subject = "Test";
message.Body = "test ";


SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
Client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: Probably you should start informing us about the _errors_.

Comment: When i click the button to send the email i get the error
Could not send the e-mail - error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Comment: What's the value of emailresult ?

Comment: It is the ID of a select query I have created to select the necessary email addresses

Comment: message.To.Add has to be an emailadres it's the recipients email, please show the emailresult value

Comment: emailresult must contain email address not ID! So remove message.To.Add(emailresult); line - to address you already specified in MainMessage constructor second parameter.

Comment: What is message.To? It is a MailAddressCollection. What is expected as parameter for the Add method of a MailAddressCollection? These simple questions are all answered and documented in MSDN. You should read the docs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The emailresult value is a varchar. Im sorry im new to C#

Comment: Please add the emailresult code to your post, it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `emailResults` is some kind of Enumerable you will need to add each email address string from the Enumerable to the MailMessage.To MailAddressCollection. It's hard to say exactly how to do this without knowing the **[Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)** of `emailresults`. I expect you need something along these lines.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("queensqsis@gmail.com", "queensqsis@gmail.com");// to & from

for(var item in emailresult){
    message.To.Add(item);
}

message.Subject = "Test";
message.Body = "test ";


SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
Client.Send(message);
```

*If you can confirm what **[Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)** `emailResults` is it will be much easier to provide a clear solution.*

Comment: Im sorry I'm new to all this. EmailResult is a select query which selects email address of students sitting a particular module

Comment: Store the result of your query in for example a dataset and loop trough this dataset with emailadresses

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code you use to get `emailresult`. I'm guessing its something like a SqlDataReader. Does your code look anything like the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: emailResult is data source calling emails in

Comment: C# is a strongly-typed language. Every variable has a type. `emailResult` has a type. What type is it? - It is very difficult to suggest how you can retrieve data from `emailResult` without knowing what type it is. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx

Comment: emailresult is a connection string, The data within emailresult is a varchar I am trying to get multiple data into a variable string so i can send multiple emails

Comment: You can't use a connectionstring like this. A connection string is a description of how to connect to a database. You need to use your connectionstring to make a connection, then use the connection to execute a query, and read the results from that query.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment above you state that emailresult is a select query result, so some sort of enumarable? Or as another poster suggested a long string separated by commas or semicolons?

Try doing one of these suggestions...

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("queensqsis@gmail.com", "queensqsis@gmail.com");// to & from

//For each item in the list, add it to the list of "To" recipients
emailresult.ForEach(r => message.To.Add(r)) ;
//OR IF THE ADDRESS IS A PROPERTY OF THE ITEM
emailresult.ForEach(r => message.To.Add(r.MyEmailAddressProperty)) ;
//OR IF emailresult is some sort of string list, "email1,email2,email3" or similar then
foreach (string oneEmail in emailresult.Split(","))
{
     message.To.Add(oneEmail);
}


message.Subject = "Test";
message.Body = "test ";


SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
Client.Send(message);
```